# Embedded Tomcat, how to replace existing web.xml meant for standard Tomcat with new logic for Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7, embedded-tomcat

Given existing `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<display-name>/</display-name>

<listener><listener-class>m.Web.startup.Listener</listener-class></listener>
<listener><listener-class>m.Store.Listener</listener-class></listener>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>                                          

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mmm.com.dispatcher.servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mmm.com.dispatcher.servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>m.Web.startup.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/Web/config/ConfigWeb.xml
            classpath:/Auth/config/ConfigAuth.xml
            classpath:/Assets/config/ConfigAssets.xml
            classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
            classpath:/App/config/ConfigApp.xml
            classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
            classpath:/Store/config/ConfigStore.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I've added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.48</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.48</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.48</version>
</dependency>
```

and attempted to do:

```
private static void c() throws LifecycleException {
    File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    
    XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
    
    servlet.setContextConfigLocation("""
        classpath:/Web/config/ConfigWeb.xml
        classpath:/Auth/config/ConfigAuth.xml
        classpath:/Assets/config/ConfigAssets.xml
        classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
        classpath:/App/config/ConfigApp.xml
        classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
        classpath:/Store/config/ConfigStore.xml
    """);
    
    Tomcat.addServlet(tomcat.addContext(tomcat.getHost(), "/", tmpDir.getAbsolutePath()), "mmm.com.dispatcher.servlet", servlet);

    new m.Web.startup.Listener();
    new m.Store.Listener();
    
    tomcat.start();
    
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

But is not working.

The server starts but several things are not working. `localhost:8080` results in an error page.

Also tried:

```
public static void e() throws LifecycleException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat() {
        @Override
        public Context addWebapp(String contextPath, String docBase) throws ServletException {
            Context context = null;
            try {
                context = new StandardContext();
                context.setName(contextPath);
                context.setPath(contextPath);
                context.setDocBase(docBase);
                context.setRealm(this.getHost().getRealm());
                ContextConfig contextConfig = new ContextConfig();
                context.addLifecycleListener(contextConfig);
                String pathToWebXml = docBase + "Store/web.xml";
                if (new File(pathToWebXml).exists()) {
                    contextConfig.setDefaultWebXml(pathToWebXml);
                } else {
                    contextConfig.setDefaultWebXml("org/apache/catalin/startup/NO_DEFAULT_XML");
                }
                host.addChild(context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error deploying webapp", e);
            }
            return context;
            
        }
    };
    tomcat.setPort(8081);
    
    Service service = tomcat.getService();
    service.addConnector(sslConnector());
    
    try {
        URL resource = TomcatServer.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".");
        
        tomcat.addWebapp("", resource.getPath());
        //add others here...
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        log.error("Problem webapp. Could be fatal?");
    }
    
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
    
}
```

But this results in errors such as :

```
WARNING: Failed to scan 

[file:/Users/j/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xercesImpl.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:182)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/j/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xercesImpl.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1198)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:701)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:240)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    ... 26 more

Jun 23, 2021 2:57:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner processURLs
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/Users/j/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:182)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/j/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1198)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:701)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:240)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    ... 26 more
```

Note that currently I am starting it from within a `static void main` from within Intellij.

The method `e()` here relies on parsing the existing web.xml file, but this is not working and it fails it seems due to lacking classpath stuff.

The first method `c()` relies on trying to replicate the configuration, but I am missing ways of trying to properly replicating it.

I am unable for instance to **add** a **Listener** in the **same** **manner**, and I am unable to configure for instance the `session-config` parameter.

The first one has no classpath issues and starts but I think some things like the listeners are not properly set up, nor their events fired.

**EDIT 1:**

Perhaps this the way to add listeners, in `c()`:

```
 Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(tomcat.getHost(), "/", tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    ctx.addApplicationListener(m.Web.startup.Listener.class.getCanonicalName());
    ctx.addApplicationListener(m.Store.Listener.class.getCanonicalName());
```

But again things start up, but still error in tomcat. Unsure if the classpath: ... in original `web.xml` mimicked in `c()` are accurately applied as well.

**EDIT 2:**

Now gotten most things up, however WebSockets (annotated in the code) is not being picked up, as well as HttpSessionListener not being triggered.

In `web.xml` you could define a listener that implemented several interfaces such as `ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener` but with embedded Tomcat this does not seem to work. I am also not able to register them separately either as of now, but that should be possible. Still annoying.

I just wish you could just feed it the web.xml and it could configure itself, just like the standalone one does. I don't get why that has to be so hard.

```
private static void c() throws LifecycleException, ServletException, URISyntaxException, DeploymentException, IOException {
    File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
                                            
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    
    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    ctx.addApplicationListener(m.Web.startup.Listener.class.getCanonicalName());
    ctx.addApplicationListener(m.Store.Listener.class.getCanonicalName());
    ctx.addApplicationListener(Listener.class.getCanonicalName());
    ctx.setSessionTimeout(30);
    
    Wrapper wrapper = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "mmm.com.dispatcher.servlet", m.Web.startup.DispatcherServlet.class.getCanonicalName());
    
    wrapper.addInitParameter("contextClass", org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.class.getCanonicalName());
    wrapper.addInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", """
        classpath:/Web/config/ConfigWeb.xml
        classpath:/Auth/config/ConfigAuth.xml
        classpath:/Assets/config/ConfigAssets.xml
        classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
        classpath:/App/config/ConfigApp.xml
        classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml
        classpath:/Store/config/ConfigStore.xml
    """);
    
    wrapper.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    
    if ( true ) {
        wrapper.addMapping("/");
    }
    else if ( false ) {
        ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/", "mmm.com.dispatcher.servlet", true);
    }
    
    tomcat.start();

    if ( false ) {
        ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(Socket.class, new URI("ws://"));
    }
    
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

Comment: How about setting xml configs on XmlWebApplicationContext like `String xmlConfigs[] = new String[] {"classpath:/Web/config/ConfigWeb.xml",
        "classpath:/Auth/config/ConfigAuth.xml",
        "classpath:/Assets/config/ConfigAssets.xml",
        "classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml",
        "classpath:/App/config/ConfigApp.xml",
        "classpath:/Accounts/config/ConfigAccounts.xml",
        "classpath:/Store/config/ConfigStore.xml"};  context.setConfigLocations(xmlConfigs);`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I tried that too, did not work. I had it on both as well.

Comment: @mmm: The errors you encounter are caused by problems in the classpath of your application. Whatever you use to start your application (your IDE?) adds non-existent files to the classpath. BTW: Tomcat 8.0 reached end-of-life 3 years ago. Switch to 8.5 or 9.0.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I got it working but now missing web socket annotation scanning. Also HttpSessionListener event is not triggered.

Comment: The web socket implementation is in the [`tomcat-embed-websocket`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket) artifact.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, I added that, however, was not able to configure it afterwards. Simply adding it is not enough. 

You are supposed to do something like: 

ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(Socket.class, new URI("ws://"));

But I have no idea what that URL is for. I don't think this is correct either. Maybe this is for connecting to a socket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat Catalina context - add existing servlet to context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253024/tomcat-catalina-context-add-existing-servlet-to-context) BTW: since you are using Spring, use Spring Boot and you don't need to worry about the details.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of Spring so I prefer not having to rely on it for anything. Only have the MVC layer left to get rid of. Might be dealt with right after this task.

Comment: It is the websocket part now that is outstanding.